# If $G$ is a group, and $S \subset G$, then how to get the a subgroup $S'$ of $G$ such that $\langle S \rangle=S'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My title might be not clear enough, but due to the character limit, I wasn't able to explicitly write in Latex.

So suppose you have a group $G$, and $S$ is a part of $G$. Now, in order to generate a subgroup $S'$ of $S$, we have a theorem stating that:

$$S' =  \left\langle S \right\rangle = \left\{  x_1^{\epsilon _1} x_2^{\epsilon _2} \cdots x_n^{\epsilon _n}\mid n \in\mathbb{N} \; \mbox{et} \; \forall i, x_i \in S, \varepsilon_i = \pm 1  \right\}.  $$

And this set just doesn't make any sense to me. Could someone give me an example of for example in case of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ how would I generate a subgroup that has $S= \{ a \mid a \: is \: prime\} $? Or any other example.

Comment: `\langle S \rangle`, not `<S>`

Comment: The subgroup of $\langle \Bbb Z,+ \rangle$ containing all prime numbers is unfortunately the group itself.

Comment: @KennyLau Made an edit accordingly! Could you suggest any other simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle S\rangle$ consists of all the group elements that you can get by starting with the elements in $S$ and applying the group operation (written as multiplication in the theorem you quoted) and taking inverses.  A priori, you would get $\langle S\rangle$ by taking all the elements of $S$, then forming all products of those elements, then forming inverses of everything you got so far, then forming products of all those things, then inverses, and so on. The theorem you quoted says that it's not really that complicated. You can just take elements of $S$ ($x_i^1$ in the theorem's notation), inverses of those ($x_i^{-1}$) and products of those ($x_1^{\pm1}x_2^{\pm1}\cdots x_n^{\pm1}$). You don't need to take inverses of these, further products, etc., because all those group elements are already included in this $S'$.  Presumably, the proof of the theorem explains that, by showing that $S'$ is a subgroup of $G$.

In your example, where the group is $\mathbb Z$ and $S$ is the set of primes, we have to remember that now the group operation is $+$ (not multiplication) and inverse are negatives. So $S'$ consists of the primes ($2,3,5,7,\dots$), their inverses ($-2,-3,-5,-7$) and all the numbers you can get from these by addition.  To see what those numbers are, notice first that you can get $1$ (by adding $-2$ and $3$), and then by adding lots of copies of $1$, you can get all the positive integers. You can also get all the negative integers by first getting $-1=2+(-3)$ and then adding lots of copies of $-1$. And you can get $0$ by adding $2$ and $-2$ (or by adding no summands). So, in your example, $S'$ is all of $\mathbb Z$.

For a more instructive example, still with the group $\mathbb Z$, think about what $S'$ is when $S=\{4,6\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The set just mean that $S^{'}$ is a subgroup generated by $S$ and it contains all the possible outcomes when elements of $S$ act on other(can be same too) element of $S$

for example take your group $G=\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$ and $S_1=\{(1,0)\}\  \text{and}\  S_2=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ then $<S_1>=\{(1,0),(0,0)\}$ and $<S_2>=\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,0)\}$

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly is $\mathbb{Z} _2$?

Comment: Set $\{0,1\}$ under addition modulo $2$ which will be a group of order 2